# Differences between audience, issuer, and client terms in JWT, OAuth and OIDC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

> **"The half of knowledge is to say I don't know when you don't" proverb**

Every time I try to keep my knowledge about these terms clear and correct. However, over the development of new projects and acquiring new knowledge (SaaS, Multi-tenancy, 2Step Verification, IdPs, SSO ), I feel like I still do not understand them correctly. Any one can give a simple and efficient explanation?

I am an ASP.NET developer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I like that quote, so, this is some answer. Let's say we have a jwt like this

```
{
   // ...Some other claim
   iss: "MyKnowledgeCenter.com",
   aud: "Abu.questioning.com",
   // ...Some more other claims
}
```

First thing is abount ***issuer***, which represent as `iss`. This indicate that where the whole Jwt you have come from. For ex: We have a request for access token at `https://abu.Identity.com`, but the issuer could be `MyKnowledgeCenter.com`, or `https://abu.Identity.com` or anything else. We have freedom to just indicate those as we code the identity centralize server ourself.

In short, `iss` is just a Jwt claim that have nothing difference from other, except it's meaning is to indicate that this jwt was `self-declared` that it came from an issuer that called `MyKnowledgeCenter.com` from this example.

About ***audience***, again, it's just a claim in Jwt, that was intended to set as we wish, represented for one or a collection of which services that the Jwt itself intended to use for.

I love example: I have 2 microservices is `Catalog` and `UserProfile`, that require client to have a Jwt was issued at `MyKnowledgeCenter.com` to access their resources. If on those 2, validating on audience is required (as we can set it), then, even if the sign is valid, but `aud` was lack of `Catalog`, client cannot access `Catalog` microservice resources. The same applied for all others.

Okay, so where's the ***client*** ?

Well, that's indicate something as setting but not re-presented in the Jwt.

Imagine, we have a centralize authentication server, but we only intend to serve our own services, and clients. Not the whole Internet world, right ?

So, specifying those specific clients would benefit, as I just want to serve an app on iOs, another from android word and a website of our own. Therefore, 3 clients. If any request that came from any other clients that have informations doesn't match one of those 3, we rejected them immediately.

Simple enough ?